# HAXM Is Not Installing (Windows 10 Home User, Hyper-V is already Not Installed)

Tags: windows, flutter, virtualization, hyper-v, haxm

Long time reader, first time poster.

I am trying to get a start on learning Flutter...however, I have everything almost installed EXCEPT for HAXM. I have tried the installer on the Android Studio as well as the individual installer found in the Release Archives of HAXM's GIT REPO (downloaded haxm-windows_v7_5_6 with failure regarding Hyper-V still running). See picture below.

```
Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\Amanda\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log2.txt"
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\Amanda\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log2.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 1/20/2020  11:44:38 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

However, Hyper-V is not installed on my machine because Hyper-V is not supported in Windows 10 Home edition. The option is not found in my Windows Features and it cannot be installed since "Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown." within powershell.  I even tried the command found in the third image below, restarted my computer, and the install STILL didn't work.

In addition to that, my SVM option within my BIOS is already marked as disabled anyways, but HAXM cannot install due to `Hyper-V being on`.  Any help will be appreciated here...

Apparently, I need reputation before posting images, please message me if you would like to see the error messages

Answer (score 9):

If your computer supports HAXM and VT-x, Firstly, check if virtualization is enabled here: [image]

If it is (it was for me on W10 Home), you need to run
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` to disable it. IDK why it was enabled for me, considered I can't use it on the Home version.. Then reboot and run the haxm installer.

Comment: I did this and now it works, but task manager still shows "activated" after running bcdedit and rebooting. but with launchtype off i could successfully install haxm. thank you

Comment: I guess this should be marked as an answer.

Comment: Please highlight the command as: ` bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`. It works!

Comment: I felt this one is the best way to do that: ````https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370701/787399````

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue running on my Windows Home after a lot of try , the solution which worked for me is going here :
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
and download the windows version of Intel Haxm and installing it and then run the emulator

Comment: This is what ultimately what worked for me after enabling virtualization through my machine's BIOS. Installing HAXM through Android Studio failed every time I tried it, before and after changing the BIOS setting

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it won't install is actually the same reason why you don't have Hyper-V in your version of windows.

Windows Home Edition does not have support for Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) and therefore does not support Hyper-V and will not support Intel HAXM.

What you can do, is install a virtual machine program such as [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/). These programs can benefit from hardware virtualization, but don't require it, so they will work even without Intel Virtualization Technology support.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting time with all those articles related to "device guard and credential guard", below are my settings and my solution:

- Windows 10 Home Single Language
- Intel core i9
- Virtualization enabled in BIOS
- Hyper-V uninstalled via "turn off windows features"

`C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose` still has "NO"s for me on "virtualization VT-x" and "Hyper-V disabled" points

The final solution came deactivating Hyper-V through command line using Powershell **run as administrator**:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and reboot after that

Bests.-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after many tries it solved by enabling 'Virtualization' in BIOS.

Here is the video showing how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQIyowZMiY8