# Android Emulator on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio and VS 2017 on Windows 10.
And I have enabled hyper-v on windows.

I have a problem at emulator as follow.
[This is an error screen on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqbPv.png)

**Error Message**

```
Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:
gpu found. vendor id 8086 device id 0x3e92
checking for bad AMD vulkan driver version...
amdvlk64.dll not found. Checking for amdvlk32...
amdvlk32.dll not found. No bad AMD Vulkan driver versions found.
checking for bad vulkan-1.dll version...
vulkan-1.dll version: 1.1.114.0
Not known bad vulkan-1.dll version; continue.
```

What's the problem?

Please if someone kind enough to help me or direct me to reach a solution. thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you can post error message as text

Comment: Yes, I post error message as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem. I unplugged the docking station and everything works.

Comment: what docking station can you please explain?

Comment: Why oh why would this be the accepted answer??? How does this help anyone?

Comment: I don't remember the brand of this docking station. I just unplugged it and plugged all my devices into the computer. Sorry, but that's all I can say about it.

Comment: This helped me. My docking station is Dell D6000.
The silly thing is that once the virtual device is started, you can re-plug into the docking station, and it works on whatever screen.
It is only the boot time of the virtual device, when the docking station must be unplugged.

Answer (score 81):

In `C:\Users\<your_name>\.android` add a file named `advancedFeatures.ini`

add these parameters inside the `advancedFeatures.ini` file

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMen = on
```

Now Start AVD

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvog7hf_i-c&ab_channel=Tr%E1%BA%A7nKha)

Comment: mine was actually in here : C:\Android\.android (make sure you can see adv folder so you know you're in the right folder)

Comment: @kiratot
It is the default folder of android at the time of installation.

Answer (score 8):

In AVD manager, click on the "Edit" icon next to your required virtual device. Then change ***emulated performance -> graphics*** from Hardware or None to ***Software***. Works like a charm.

Comment: that one is the most simple one

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using two different SO answers.

- I needed to change the Emulated Performance Graphics option to Software, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392200/137670.  If your Graphics option is enabled that should do it.
- My Graphics option was not enabled, so I used this answer to enable it:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376934/137670

Comment: Changing to Software for the Graphics Performance worked for me. I was running Android Studio within a Virtual Machine on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved this issue.
I don't know why it causes troubles but Vulkan-rt doesn't work properly when the Bandicam app is downloaded on PC.

1. Download the `amdvlk64.dll` f.e. here - [first offered web site in google search](https://www.dll-files.com/download/14104c02571200ddd25264fe4e70e4ed/amdvlk64.dll.html?c=Z3NDNVErSU1OMTJsS2xTZWNHbW5Rdz09)
2. Unzip it and put `amdvlk64.dll` file into the `C:\Windows\System32` (if Win10)
3. Delete 'Bandicam' through the system.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error suddenly while I am running my code. So how I solve the problem is,

- Go to AVD Manager.
- Edit your AVD.
- Select 'Software GLES2.0' option on    Emulated Performance.
- Click Finish.
- Start AVD again.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQbWz.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because of the Hyper-V enabled.

Please disable Hyper-V and try again.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

### This Comment worked finely!
I faced this error after re-installing windows ...

In C:\Users<your_name>.android
add file advancedFeatures.ini

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMen = on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370701/2227743).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30714792)