# Android Emulator closed because of an internal error: GPU Found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I haven't been on Android Studios in a number of days. When I went back on my emulator kept getting killed. I deleted all my emulators and the AVD manager folder in .android. After selecting that the emulator graphics be Software GLES 2.0 the emulator works and can run the application but it is very, very slow. Only a week ago the emualtor and Android Studios worked great.

I am receiving this error messaging now after re-installing an emulator with API level 28 (Pie):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213035/111148

Comment: I believe this post gonna help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed

Comment: I had exact the same issue and able to fix only after manually disabling my non-using video card in device manager.

Answer (score 26):

**Answer that work [28. July 2021]**

1. First of all update your graphic card with the latest driver. (Graphic Card Model can be checked through your `Device Manager`)
2. Type in your explorer the following path, where `<pc_name>` need to be replaced with your individual name:

> C:\Users<pc_name>.android

3. In the above mentioned directory we will put a `.ini` file that I prepared and is ready to [download here](https://workupload.com/file/aRZAW7SSjLX). This file will disable your `Vulkan driver` and enable your `GLDirect driver` that your `AVD`s don't lag anymore. (watch image below)
4. Start your `AVD` and you will be able to use it without any troubles.

[image: Where you have to put the file]

Comment: I do not have an AMD chip, I have an Intel CPU.

Comment: Hello, what is the solution for MacOS developer?

Comment: doesn't work for me on windows 10

Comment: Worked with integrated graphic intel UHD 610 on windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.1, Android 4.2.2
Thank you so much!

Comment: worked for me on windows 10 and android studio artic fox....

Comment: Hi @DEX7RA! Working well. Thank you very much.

Comment: worked for me on Windows 11 as well, thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is a missing or corrupted file amdvlk64.dll.I fixed this by given steps.

1. Download amdvlk64.dll from [This Link](https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=amdvlk64.dll&arch=64bit&version=1.0.54.0) , this is for 64 bit OS, you can search fro 32 bit also.
2. After Download, extract the folder on your desktop.
3. Open Extracted folder and Copy the amdvlk64.dll file.
4. Now Paste this file in C:\Windows\System32
5. Again run the emulator, hopefully it will run.

Comment: the file in this link seems to be damaged

Answer (score 4):

In my case I resolved this by performing the pending SDK Tools updates in the SDK Manager.
Reference : https://superuser.com/a/1583394/961460

Answer (score 3):

I get this error (Emulator is closed because of internal error: gpu found)

suddenly while I am running my code. So how I solve the problem is,

Go to AVD Manager or (Virtual Device Manager).

Edit your AVD or (Virtual Device Manager).

Select 'Software GLES2.0' option on Emulated Performance.

Click Finish.

Start AVD again

Comment: This solved for me on an Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this [vulkan-dll driver](https://workupload.com/start/8bNrSdFuF65).

There are those who think that the comment I added is a virus, I researched the subject a lot and finally reached the address, almost 48 hours later, so I installed my emulator, my aim is just to help.

Comment: I am voting to close and delete this answer because link only answers are considered **very low quality** since it doesn't directly give the answer to the question and doesn't directly solve the problem. Links to documentations etc are usually just **an addition for reference to the answer** that you have gave to solve the problem that the person is asking. Consider adding some more explanation or your answer could end up get **deleted or closed**

Answer (score 0):

For me, the same error showed even though I have NVIDIA GPU.
Restarting the system after the NVIDIA driver update fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed  Android studio in Windows 10(AMD Ryzen), the following one helped me to run the emulator smoothly. Once you installed Virtual device from AVD manager successfully, then your emulator will popup the above error like **Android emulator closed....amdvlk64.dll not found and amdvlk32.dll not found....** when you try to run your code. Just follow this steps to avoid those error, hope it works:

1. Close your Android studio and also emulator error popup. Go to
   Control Panel.
2. Select Programs --> Programs and Features --> Turn windows feature
   on or off (which lies in the extreme right side of the screen).
3. A popup appears, in that check the **Windows Hypervisor Platform and
   Virtual Machine Platform**, then click Ok.
4. It ask you to restart your system, allow to restart.
5. After restart, now open   Android studio and run your emulator, hope it will
   run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

At times the error might be caused by the wrong system date/time set on your computer. Try updating the system date/time and restart the android emulator. In my case it was caused by the wrong system date/time.