# Android Emulator is closed because of internal error: gpu found. Vendor id 8086

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

[Got a problem with starting the android emulator. i already tried reinstalling and updating the drivers too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDjOE.png)

Comment: See if this question solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828/android-studio-suddenly-got-gpu-driver-issue-when-running-emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316340/android-emulator-closed-because-of-an-internal-error-gpu-found Here's another one