# Android Emulator closed because of an internal error (vendor id 1002)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

Got a problem with starting android emulator.
I noticed it after updating some sdk, maybe intel emulator accelerator (HAXM) or android emulator. maybe the problem appeared before, but I noticed it only after that.

Drivers updated to the latest version, sdk too, tried reinstalling the studio and change the graphics parameters of the emulator - did not help.

Processor - intel i3-10100F
Video card - ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series (miners decided so)

Also saw, some news about CSGO and Vulcan, and I sometimes play (respectively, upgrading to the latest versions), maybe it has something to do?

Thank a lot you in advance for your response)
[When trying to open the emulator this appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzrV3.png)

Comment: I downloaded version 9 of android and everything runs fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the following helped me:

In C:\Users<your_name>.android add file advancedFeatures.ini

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMen = on
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68370701/13909927