# Android 12 arm64 emulator not working on windows 10

Tags: android, windows-10, android-emulator, android-12

I am trying to start emuator with Android 12 and facing  issue.Attached is the screenshot for error.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277774/android-emulator-on-windows-10) questions answer's and tried adding

```
In C:\Users\<your_name>\.android add file advancedFeatures.ini 

Vulkan = off  
GLDirectMen = on
```

I also added amdvlk64.dll file into the C:\Windows\System32 folder but that also didn't helped[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfisV.png)

Comment: If you're still dealing with this, what happens if you run `emulator -debug-init -avd avd-name` directly? I'm not sure how you launch emulator.exe on Windows (probably as simple as opening a cmd window in `Android\Sdk\Emulator`), but once you've figured that out, `emulator -list-avds` is the simplest way to get the transformed AVD name (which replaces spaces with dashes) to use at the commandline. What debug output do you get? Pasting the whole thing would probably be most useful, the presumably-approximate location data seems to be the only sensitive info in it.

Comment: what's your processor?

Comment: @iamanbansal computer processor:- CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz

Comment: You can not run ARM64 emulator on x86 processor (i5). Use x86 emulator

Comment: It seems like that error log continues on. Could you post the entire error?