# Android Emulator fails to open

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am unable to run the android emulator. It keeps throwing this error. Any suggestions on how to fix?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277774/android-emulator-on-windows-10)

Comment: make sure your graphic card is updated, then go to device manager and click on edit this avd.  
 in emulated performance section change graphic setting from automatic to Software-GLES 2.0  and run the emulator again

Answer (score 1):

just create the file with the name `advancedFeatures.ini` open it and paste this text

`Vulkan = off GLDirectMem = on`

after pasting the text then save the file, copy the file and then paste to this location on your computer `C:\Users\Your User Name\.android`. After all, this process restart your computer, then enjoy your emulator

Comment: Hi, thank you. The emulator does start up now on android studio. However, it fails to do so on vscode - Failed to launch Pixel 3 XL API 30: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds.